# Zend_Validate_Float fails to validate zero

Tags: zend-validate

This is the piece of code and this doesnt take zero as an input value. But it does validate well with floating point and integer values.
I have tried with setting the locale, but that too doesnt seem to work.

```
$commNotEmpty = new Zend_Validate_Float();
$commNotEmpty->setMessage('Please enter a numeric value');

$this->comm = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('comm');
$this->comm->class ='full_width';
$this->comm->addValidators(array($commNotEmpty));
```